# Why, in physics, isn't the law of sine used as often as the law of cosine?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, physics

When dealing with vector quantities (like force) in physics, we often have to either decompose the vector into appropriate components or find the length of the opposite side of a non-right-angle triangle.

To give a more specific example, for those who know physics, I can mention the way the distance between a mass element and the point P in the proof of Newton's shell theorem (see the diagram below).

[image]

Back to the original point, in the process of expressing this distance we use the cosine law, not the sine law; and indeed, if I apply the sine law, the expression for $dF$ (force element) becomes a bit dirty and very hard to integrate. But I'm curious why that is. The sine law is much simpler than the cosine law, but why is this happening? Or am I wrong and is it possible to use the sine law in integration?

Comment: I don't see how you've got a choice: you know two sides $r,R$ and the included angle $\theta$, you need the cosine rule to get the opposite side.

Comment: If you define a new angle $\phi$ of the point P, considering a traingle including P, then I think it's really natural to think about the sine law to be applied to find $\cos \phi = \sqrt{1 - \sin ^2 \phi}$ in terms of $\sin \theta$?

Comment: But when we integrate the annulus to get the whole sphere $\theta$ runs naturally from $0$ to $\pi$; the angle $\phi$  runs from $0$ up to something then back down to $0$, which would throw me; moreover the annulus is naturally of thickness $R d\theta$, I don't think it is as easily expressed in terms of $\phi$. I'd also echo @Quanto's answer.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Because here I was integrating the force, i.e. $\int dF$, not the surface area itself, there was definitely a need to consider other things as well.

Comment: But surely $dF$ is proportional to the area of the annulus?

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yes, because the mass element is the product of the density and the area.

Comment: So my original remark stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A purely heuristic argument perhaps runs as follows. Classical mechanics assumes Euclidean geometry to be the underlying geometry, where, given two vectors $u,v$, with an angle of $\theta$ between them, the cosine-law is expressed as follows

$$\|u\pm v\|^2=\|u\|^2\pm2\cos\theta\cdot \|u\|\cdot\|v\|+\|v\|^2$$

and since in many cases a quantity of interest is in fact $\|u\pm v\|$ ,(given $u,v$), the cosine rule seems to be more susceptible than the sine rule.

Answer (score 2):

The sine law may appear simple, perhaps only deceptively so, at least for your example where $\theta$ is the only known angle. Because the sine law would require two angles, instead of just $\theta$ as in the cosine law.

If you eliminate the second angle in terms of $\theta$ in the sine law, you would end up with the same expression of the cosine law.